# Convert Notes field to JsonJavaArray

Tags: java, json, xpages

In my XPages application I am using the com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject class for a lis of contact details (phone list).

The object I want to bind to a repeat control that will display all the contact details of a contact.

I want to save the values for a JsonJavaArray to a Notes field and when I display the document via an XPage I want to read it in again so I have to convert it.

Here is how the json is saved in the field:

```
{
    "locations": [
        {
            "lat": "23.053",
            "long": "72.629",
            "location": "ABC",
            "address": "DEF",
            "city": "Ahmedabad",
            "state": "Gujrat",
            "phonenumber": "1234567"
        },
        {
            "lat": "23.053",
            "long": "72.629",
            "location": "ABC",
            "address": "DEF",
            "city": "Ahmedabad",
            "state": "Gujrat",
            "phonenumber": "1234567"
        },
        {
            "lat": "23.053",
            "long": "72.629",
            "location": "ABC",
            "address": "DEF",
            "city": "Ahmedabad",
            "state": "Gujrat",
            "phonenumber": "1234567"
        },
        {
            "lat": "23.053",
            "long": "72.629",
            "location": "ABC",
            "address": "DEF",
            "city": "Ahmedabad",
            "state": "Gujrat",
            "phonenumber": "1234567"
        },
        {
            "lat": "23.053",
            "long": "72.629",
            "location": "ABC",
            "address": "DEF",
            "city": "Ahmedabad",
            "state": "Gujrat",
            "phonenumber": "1234567"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is how I read the field and convert it to a jsonobject and read the array:

```
String codeString = doc.getItemValueString(fieldName);
JsonJavaObject objJson = new JsonJavaObject(codeString);                
JsonJavaArray arrJson = objJson.getAsArray("locations");
```

The error I get is as followed:

> Error in com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject, line 56:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 1

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You want to check if your codestring came back as valid Json and then check what elements your actual jsonjava object

Comment: I think it is. At least according the json.lint website. Or are you not meaning this? How should I check it is valid or should I store it in a different format?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the JsonParser to create a JSON object from a String object e.g.

```
JsonJavaObject objJson = (JsonJavaObject) JsonParser.fromJson(JsonJavaFactory.instanceEx, codeString);
```

More examples can be found here:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonParser